# More effective way of handling applying classes with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

For examples sake, lets say I have 3 web pages and a functions.php file.

- index.php
- shop.php
- contact.php
- functions.php

On each page there should be a navigation.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class=""> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#">Shop</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And there is a variable set on each page manually. index = 1, shop =2 and contact = 3.

**Example:**

```
$page_id = 1;
```

Instead of putting the navigation on each page, I'd rather use a function to output the navigation code onto the page and have it automatically set the `.active` class on the correct `<li>` depending on the current $page_id variable that is set on each page manually. Index = 1, shop =2 and contact = 3.

**Example of Index.php:**

```
<?php $page_id=1; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
etc....
```

When it comes to outputting the navigation, I use the function
`getNaviation($page_id);` in the space of where the navigation code would be in html.

```
<nav>
  <ul><?php getNaviation($page_id); ?></ul>
</nav>
```

**Functions.php**

```
<?php getNavigation($id) {

 switch ($id) {
     case 1:
         echo "
             <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Shop</a> </li>
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
             ";
         break;
     case 2:
         echo "
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
             <li class="active"> <a href="#">Shop</a> </li>
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
             ";
         break;
     case 3:
         echo "
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Shop</a> </li>
             <li class="active"> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
             ";
         break;
     default:
         echo "
             <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Shop</a> </li>
             <li class=""> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
             ";
         break;
       }//end of switch

}//end of getNavigation ?>
```

What I'm wondering is whether there is much 'cleaner' and more flexible/effective way of achieving the same result with less code? I would preferably like to achieve this just using pure PHP rather than something like jQuery.

Since this is only mock data, as you can imagine, that switch statement will become increasingly large due to the amount of pages possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the page urls in an `assoc_array` and compare with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

```
<?php
function activeClass ($href) {
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $href) {
       return "active";
   }
}
$hrefs = array (
   "/home" => "Home Page",
   "/shop" => "Shop",
   "/contact" => "Contact",
);
?>

<?php foreach($hrefs as $href=>$text): ?>
    <li class="<?=activeClass($href) >">
        <a href="<?=$href>">
          <?=$text ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; // all hrefs ?>
```